# get and set color of pixel

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to set color for pixel.

When I try to set color of a certain pixel(by clicking left mouse button). My mouse function.

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
    pixel *p = new pixel();
    p->x = x;
    p->y = HEIGHT - y;
    stack.push(p);

    float arr[3];
    readPixel(p->x, p->y, arr);

    std::cout<<"pixel color: ";
    std::cout<<arr[0]<<" "<<arr[1]<<" "<<arr[2]<<std::endl;

    drawPixel(p->x, p->y);
}
}
```

Here `readPixel` method

```
void readPixel(int x, int y, float (&a)[3]) {

GLubyte arr[3];
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, arr);

a[0] = (float)arr[0] / 255.0f;
a[1] = (float)arr[1] / 255.0f;
a[2] = (float)arr[2] / 255.0f;
};
```

The problem is with setting color for pixel.
I create structure `pixel` with fields `x` and `y`. When I click left button, object `pixel` is added to stack. 
When I try to set color for pixel(draw it) - pixel does not change its color in method `drawPixel`

```
void draw() {

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
if (!stack.empty()) {
    drawPixel(stack.top()->x, stack.top()->y);
    stack.pop();
}
glEnd();

glFlush();
};

void drawPixel(int x, int y) {

glRasterPos2i(x, y); 
glDrawPixels(1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &val);

};
```

Where `&val` is `float val[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };`
So the question is **how to set color for pixel with coordinates x and y?**

Comment: Please don't use `new` for an array of only 3 elements (you got a memory leak BTW). Make `readPixel` accept a pointer to a preallocated array, and allocate the array from the stack.

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return anything? When you step through your code in a debugger, what do you see?

Comment: I didn't use `glGetError()`. Also I've solved first question. Debugger for `drawPixel` doesn't show any problem - all parameters are correct. However pixel does not change color when I click on it.

Comment: OpenGL output isn't persistent.  You need to draw the pixel over again on each draw cycle.  Also, you want `val` and not `&val`, since an array will decay to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: So I can't pop elements from stack?

Comment: @user1432980: Leaving the items in the stack would probably fix your issue, yes.  You still have the problem that this is terrible terrible style for use of OpenGL.

Comment: in your `glDrawPixels` call, you have an array of `float`, and use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.  Since those don't match, it won't work the way you expect.

Comment: I get it. I change `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` to `GL_FLOAT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` to `GL_FLOAT` and not `pop` items from stack